# How can I visualize Fortran (90 or later) source code, e.g. using Graphviz?

Tags: graph, fortran, visualization, graphviz

I've been thrown into a large Fortran project with a large number of source files.

I need to contribute to this project and it would seem prudent that I first understand the source.

As a first step, I'd like to visualize the interdependences between the various source files, i.e. which source files need which modules. As far as I can tell, automated methods exist for other languages and result in a graph that can be built using Graphviz.

But is anyone aware of software out there that can do this for Fortran 90 code?

[Searching the interwebs for Fortran help is a real pain as you end up searching the inter-cobwebs thanks to the painfully ubiquitous FORTRAN 77.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have money then [Understand for Fortran](http://scitools.com/?gclid=CJTno6y5zKICFds_3god7wMX0w) is worth looking at.  If you don't have money but intend to work quickly then you might get by with a trial download of the software.

For a static call graph, I've never found a free tool as useful as Understand; it's hard to find any free tools let alone a useful one.  I'd write one myself but the market would be tiny :-(

For a dynamic call graph investigate your compiler options.  I use the Intel Fortran Compiler which can generate a mound of useful information about an executing program.  The TotalView debugger can also visualise the call graph of an executing program.  You should also look at [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) which makes a DOT file out of a GPROF call 'graph'.  This is free and OK.

And I should also add, though it's not something I've ever used, that [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) may be of use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, Understand for Fortran does seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 25):

I would recommend [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), which automatically generates documentation from source code (and is free). Usually you add some markup to comments describing your functions and variables. However, you can just run doxygen on undocumented source files, provided you set `EXTRACT_ALL` to `YES` in the configuration file, and have it create create relationship diagrams for all your functions (i.e. this function call these functions and is called by these other functions).

You need GraphViz installed to get diagrams generated and have the `HAVE_DOT` option set to `YES` in the configuration file.

See the doxygen documentation for [graphs and diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) for more information and this [example class documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/diagrams/html/class_a.html) for a example of the output generated.

**Edit**: Of course for Fortran you should set the `OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN` option to `YES` in the configuration file.

Comment: This method worked for me using the available Ubuntu packages for `doxygen` and `graphviz`. The options Chris refers to are found in the `Doxyfile` configuration file.

Comment: There's also a `doxywizard` program in the `doxygen-ui` package that makes things pretty simple

Comment: I tried both, doxygen and Understand, and I must say the doxygen does an awesome job. In the configuration file I use: HAVE_DOT=YES, CALL_GRAPH=YES, CALLER_GRAPH=YES, and finally EXTRACT_ALL=YES to include *all* the Fortran files in the subdirectories.

Comment: @naught101 It's `doxygen-gui` not `doxygen-ui`, at least it's on modern ubuntu distributions

Comment: For readers new to Doxygen: there is a brief descriptions of Chris' solution available [here](http://www.softeng-support.ac.uk/documents/2013/06/05/fortran-callgraph-doxygen.html). Possibly it is copied from here - not sure.

Comment: For the sake of information, doxygen does not produce dynamic call graphs, it parses the source code _without_ running it and creates call graphs. For run-time call graphs a debugger or compiler flags are  probably the way to go...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful instructions. I spent some time figuring out that I had to set `CALL_GRAPH = YES` in the configuration options file. Edit: In fact, this was already pointed out above by @netzpurist but I'll leave this comment in case someone like me doesn't read all the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `callgrind` from within [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/):

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind [your program]
```

This will produce a `callgrind.out.[pid]` file. This works best if you compile your program without optimisations, and with debug flags.

You then have a couple of options for viewing the data:

1. Convert the callgrind output to a .dot file with [grof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot), and then view it with [xdot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py), or convert it to a static graph with GraphViz.
2. View it directly with [Kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) (includes source analysis, and call graphs).