# Fortran compilers/viewers that let you see the dependencies of a given module

Tags: fortran

I'm using PowerGREP to find all the dependencies of a module and of module variables of a Fortran code, but it's not an interface that's idealized for this. Can anyone suggest any other tools for this?

For example, I'd like to see every .f90 file where the type with the `day` label is used (see code below).

I use Windows 7, but feel free to mention anything that works on Linux too.

```
! $Id: ESMF_DateMod.F,v 1.1.6.1 2002/04/24 03:25:46 erik Exp $
module ESMF_DateMod
!===============================================================================
!BOP
! !MODULE: ESMF_DateMod
!
! !USES:
use ESMF_TODMod
use ESMF_CalendarMod
use ESMF_TimeMod
!
! !PUBLIC TYPES:
type ESMF_Date
private
sequence
type(ESMF_Calendar) calendar
integer(8) year
integer(8) month
integer(8) day
type(ESMF_TOD) tod
integer(8) julianDay
integer(8) dayOfYear
end type ESMF_Date
```

Comment: Voted to move this to StackOverflow (where it belongs).

Answer (score 2):

Not a compiler, but there is [SciTools Understand](http://www.scitools.com/), which supports several languages, Fortran included (they also keep up with the times in respect to the latest Standards). If I'm understanding your question right, it is a specialized tool for precisely that kind of analysis.

Comment: Cool - thanks! Yeah, I don't need a compiler - just a viewer. I'm trying it out right now, but the full program costs $995. =/

Comment: @InquilineKea - I used to use an old version (not sure which one but it was some 5 years ago so I could hazard a guess) and for rewriting/maintaining large projects it's a lifesaver (modernizing f77/90 to more modern form of f2003+intel's compiler extensions as well as adding some functionality). We had a few licenses at the office, and it is well worth its price. True, it is a little high price for personal needs, but nowadays what software price isn't? And if the business model is solid, the price of software tools isn't usually hard to justify.

Comment: If your codebase isn't too big, you could do this kind of job by hand (get yourself a big sheet of paper and literally draw it down).

Comment: Yeah - the version of SciTools Understand is actually incredibly helpful for my needs (I posted what I did over at http://astroclimatology.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/4-september-2011-0720/ ). And it will be for 13 more days or so. The thing is, I'm an undergrad student, and definitely can't afford to fork over $995. Maybe something less than $100 though.

Comment: The CAM3 codebase is huge though - it's much faster if I do it this way (the graphics diagrams are also very helpful in SciTools)

Comment: @InquilineKea - Download and reuse trial versions ?

Comment: I can only use them once across each computer, and only one of them is fast. I can reuse it twice (across my two other computers), but beyond that, it will be difficult.

Comment: @InquilineKea - Well, it seems to me you've got three options: a) buy a copy b) fiddle with the trial copy or c) find somewhere an illegal copy (I wouldn't recommend the last one, but I realize it is an option for some). I unfortunatelly don't know of any alternative programs of the kind, sorry ...

Comment: Yeah I know. Thanks for all the help though - I really appreciated it all.

Answer (score 2):

A [UNIX and Linux Forums post](http://www.unix.com/programming/142648-fortran-dependency-checking.html) suggests [`ftnchek`](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/~ftnchek/), which may not be the most user-friendly way to accomplish this task but has the advantage of being free.

Comment: Also, a bit outdated. It does not support modern Fortran features; well, at least it didn't the last time I tried it; and the above is clearly one of the newer flavours. +1 nevertheless, for it's good that it's here, at least as a reference to those working with f77 code.

Comment: Oh - thanks very much! I think my code is f90, but I'll look more into it.

Comment: @InquilineKea - Your code is definitely of f90 variety or newer (depending on what features you use). Hint: MODULE

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this, but I would recommend [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), which automatically generates documentation from source code. See the doxygen documentation for [graphs and diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) for more information and this [example class documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/diagrams/html/class_a.html) for a example of the output generated (note this example demonstrates the relationship between some C++ classes, but the same diagrams can be drawn for functions and subroutines in Fortran programs).

Note that time answer is similar to a previous answer of mine, which can be found here: [How can I visualize Fortran (90 or later) source code, e.g. using Graphviz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161564/how-can-i-visualize-fortran-90-or-later-source-code-e-g-using-graphviz/8893307#8893307) This answer contains a bit more information on configuring doxygen.